# VB.NET LINQ Find distinct set of objects

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following query in vb.net:

```
Using context = New abcContext()
Dim info = From t in context.class1
           Join u in context.class2  on t.id Equals u.id
           Join v in context.class3  on t.id Equals v.id and t.date Equals v.date
           Select t, u, v
           Distinct
    End Using
```

This code is translated into (roughly) the following sql:

```
select *
from class1 e1
inner join 
class2  e2
on e1.id = e2.id
inner join 
class3 e3
on e1.id = e3.id 
and e1.date = d3.date
```

So, the linq query isn't using the distinct keyword when querying the database.

Is there a simple way that I can get linq to create a query which uses the distinct keyword? (i.e. select distinct * from e1 ....)

Or is linq incapable of this when querying multiple entities?

Comment: You could perhaps convert the query response to a list using list= info.ToList() and then run “list.Distinct()” on it

Comment: @phillip556677 I've tried that, but since they're entities, the query.distinct() doesn't filter out the duplicates.  I think it would need some way of comparing all the individual entities within the query, which (unless there's a generalized form of Iequatable(Of T) that loops through every mapped item in the class) is going to be fairly time consuming.

Comment: If the id property is always unique you could maybe use Info.ToList().GroupBy(x=>x.id).select(a=>a.first())

Comment: Yeah, that seems to do the trick.  Thanks!  My only concern is that it's going to be running on tables with millions of rows, so it will cause a performance hit (because we're processing in memory instead of database-side).

Comment: When I test this, I get `SELECT DISTINCT` in the SQL. I think there is something else in your model that is causing the `DISTINCT` to be left out. What version / type of EF?

Comment: I'm using LINQ to Entities in  EF 6.1.3.
My models have both mapped and unmapped properties, if that makes a difference.